# como tabulo una matriz de 4 x 4 estatica, que contenga numeros aleatorios?

Tags: java

como tabulo una matriz de 4 x 4 estatica, que contenga numeros aleatorios?
3|3|3|3
3|4|4|4
1|4|6|6
1|5|6|5
Algo asi pero con valores aleatorios, ademas de generar 1 para diferentes jugadores

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hola te dejo este dummy code espero te ayude a resolver tu problema

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandNumbers {

    static int lfsr = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[][] = new int[4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = (rand() % 9) + 1; // valores aleatorios entre 1 y 9
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");// salto de linea
        }

    }

    /**
     * Funcion alternativa para generar numeros aleatorios
     * @author Roddy
     * {@link} 
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602919/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-without-rand-function
     */
    public static int rand() {
        int bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 5)) & 1;
        return Math.abs(lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 15));
    }
}
```